# I want the EventListener method that works with this player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

Tags: java, android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x, exoplayer-media-item

I used this but the app freezes.

player.addListener(new Player.Listener() {

```
        @Override

        public void onPlaybackStateChanged(int playbackState) {

            switch (playbackState) {

                case Player.STATE_IDLE:

                    prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

                case Player.STATE_BUFFERING:

                    prg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    break;

                case Player.STATE_READY:

                    prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

                case Player.STATE_ENDED:

                    prg.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

            }

        }

    });
```

Because I use this.
player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

Comment: Share the complete code so that someone can understand where the problem is. Also specify more details about "what library you are using?", "what do you want to achieve?" "what problem you are facing?"

Comment: player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
spv.setPlayer(player);
MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(uri);
player.setMediaItem(mediaItem);
player.prepare();
player.setPlayWhenReady(true);